# Question about exim4 config syntax

Tags: configuration, exim

I'm trying to send a notification to the sender of a message when a message is send to exactly one address in the local domain (test@mydomain.com).

Q1: How would be the syntax for the condition (the above don't work) ? :

```
notify_reply:
    driver=accept
    domains = +local_domains
    senders = ! ^.*-request@.*:\
            ! ^bounce-.*@.*:\
            ! ^.*-bounce@.*:\
            ! ^owner-.*@.*:\
            ! ^postmaster@.*:\
            ! ^webmaster@.*:\
            ! ^listmaster@.*:\
            ! ^mailer-daemon@.*:\
            ! ^root@.*:\
            ! ^noreply@.*

    condition = ${if eq {$received_for}{test@mydomain.com}}

    no_expn
    transport=notify_transport
    unseen
    no_verify
```

Q2: How to write multiline string in the config file for "text" ? :

```
notify_transport:
    driver=autoreply
    from=info@mydomain.com
    to=$sender_address
    subject=Your mail for
    text="Please resend your messasge to

info@mydomain.com

This is a temporary modification."
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Q1: conditions operate on the strings "true"/"yes" or "no"/"false", so you have to make the end result of your expansions be one of those strings.  Likewise, `${if` doesn't return an absolute true or false, it evaluates the statement and then returns strings based on the truth of the statement (you left those strings off).  Here're some example:

```
g3 0 /home/jj33 > exim -be
> ${if eq{string}{string}{true}{false}}
true
> ${if eq{string}{STRING}{true}{false}}
false
> ${if eqi{string}{STRING}{true}{false}}
true
>
```

It's important to note that the "true" and "false" strings are arbitrary, you `${if` can return any value, but true and false are the most useful to you here.  Anyhoo, based on the condition you list, I would change it to this:

```
condition = ${if eq {$received_for}{test@mydomain.com}{yes}{no}}
```

EDIT: I think newer versions of exim may not require the extra "if-true" and "if-false" parts, so I may be barking up the wrong tree here.  I think that $received_for is probably actually not the variable you want, I doubt that it contains anything at the time you are running that router.  Instead, try this:

```
condition = ${if eqi{$local_part@$domain}{test@mydomain.com}}
```

Q2: There are a few ways to solve this problem, but I like to use the ${expand: operator:

```
g3 0 /home/jj33 > exim -be
> ${expand:line1\nline2}
line1
line2
```

So, in your case, it would be:

```
text=${expand:Please resend your messasge to\n\ninfo@mydomain.com\n\nThis is a temporary modification.}
```